# Child Fork Process using fork() and pipe()

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe

I have to create a pipe that creates two child processes with fork(). Child 1 redirects stdout to the write end of the pipe and then executes with execlp() the "ls -al" command. Child 2 redirects its input from stdin to the read end of the pipe, then it executes the "sort -n -k 5" command. After creating both children, the parent process waits for them to terminate before it can exit. When I run my code, it gives the following output:

```
pipes
pipes.c
pipes.c~
```

The parent program does the same thing as a shell that runs the command "ls -al | sort -r -n -k 5". When I do this from the command line, I get the following:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 username username 8910 May 28 21:52 pipes
drwxrwxr-x 3 username username 4096 May 28 13:52 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 username username 4096 May 28 21:52 .
-rwxrwxr-x 1 username username 1186 May 28 21:52 pipes.c
-rwxrwxr-x 1 username username 1186 May 28 19:48 pipes.c~
```

Is there something im not doing correctly in my code to get the output? Any tips?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   // for strlen
#include <stdlib.h>   // for exit
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main() {
    int pipes[2];
    pid_t child1, child2;


//PIPE

        int p = pipe(pipes);
        if (p<0){   //PIPE FAILS
             fprintf(stderr, "PIPE FAIL");
             exit(2);
        }

//CHILD2 PROCESS
              child2 = fork(); //CREATING CHILD2
        if(child2 < 0){//FORK FAIL
              fprintf(stderr, "CHILD2 FORK FAILED\n\n");
              exit(3);
        }else if(child2 > 0){ //PARENT

//CHILD1 PROCESS
              child1 = fork(); //CREATING CHILD1
        if(child1 <0){//FORK FAIL
              fprintf(stderr, "CHILD1 FORK FAILED\n\n");
              exit(4);
        }else if(child1 ==0){//CHILD1 P
              dup2(pipes[1], 1);
              close(pipes[0]);
              execlp("ls","-al",NULL);
        }
              wait(NULL);//PARENT WAITS
        }
         else if(child2 ==0){ //CHILD2
              dup2(pipes[0],0);
              close(pipes[1]);

              execlp("sort", "-r", "-n", "-k" , "5", NULL);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`exec` and friends expect you to provide all the arguments for the new program's `argv` vector.  Remember that by convention, `argv[0]` is the name of the program, and the command-line arguments begin at `argv[1]`.

But you are not providing an `argv[0]` argument, so for example `ls` thinks it was called through a symbolic link named `-al` and not given any arguments.

The right way is

```
execlp("ls", "ls", "-al", NULL);
```